# Can FileBeat ship data from an MSSQL database to the Elastic Cloud? (to be used for a search function on a website)

Tags: sql-server, elasticsearch, logstash, filebeat

I have a .NET website that needs to have a search function. I need it to search my MSSQL database so I've been researching and from what I have read the newest way to do this is to use filebeat to ship data to logstash and use elasticsearch to search it. (I hope that is correct but I am new to elastic)

The part that doesn't make sense is that a lot of places I've seen are only using filebeat to ship logs.

I don't need to ship the logs from the database... 
What I need is a live search function on the database.

I think I read that I could just use logstash directly, or even elasticsearch directly I think, but I'm pretty sure I read or heard somewhere that using filebeat is the most proper and up to date way.

Can anyone tell me if I have the right assumptions about filebeat? (Ex: Is it just for logs or is it for a lot more than that too [like db data etc.])

Comment: Is this an on-premises SQL Server? It has it's own search function. Introducing additional components introduces complexity and latency. Latency means this is not actually a live search on the database. https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/298/implementing-sql-server-full-text-search-in-an-asp-net-mvc-web-application-with-entity-framework

Comment: A quick read of this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/filebeat-module-mssql.html indicates that filebeat only works with your SQL Server _error_ logs. You want to search actual data right? Based on my brief research, filebeat and elastic search are definitely not the right solution, but you really need to do your own research and be more specific in your question.

Comment: I know I can search things directly in SQL but elasticsearch has a much much better algorithm. I have seen some people say you can use filebeat to ship sql data to elastic but I wasnt sure. And elasticsearch is pretty fast so im not worried about latency with them really. @Nick.McDermaid

Comment: Have you seen SQL Server full text functionality? I suspect there may not be as much of a gap as you think. Shipping data introduces a whole bunch of new problems. Latency is one of them. What is the minimum acceptable time before adding a product to the database and being able to search for it? 1 second, 1 minute, 1 day? Based on your limited description I don't see any reason to introduce the complexity of additional products + additional latency when most likely free text search does what you want.

Comment: I’ll admit sql full text is more extensive than I thought but it still can’t search by tags and categories right?

Comment: Categories and tags are just database fields right? You don't even need full text for that, just a SQL query. In all likelihood you _do_ need functionality in elasticsearch, but I see no evidence of it in your question. I'm always wary of increasing solution footprint (number if disparate components) without a good reason.

Comment: When I talk about latency I mean the time between creating an entry in SQL Server, and it actually appearing in the elasticsearch catalog. This might be acceptable but it does introduce the concept of "I just created a product when can I search on it? answer: sometime in the next 2 - 30 minutes". I will say that the good part of moving your search into something external is that is reduces load on the database. Here is an example I found of setting up elasticsearch on SQL Server. No it doesn't use filebeat. https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/it-ops/elasticsearch-and-sql-server

Comment: BTW this was the top link when I googled "elasticsearch on sql server". The information is at your fingertips. This is all _so_ much easier than when I started my career in IT

Comment: Yeah I have found plenty of examples on how to do this without filebeat, many using logstash or elasticsearch directly. I came here hoping someone might have more experience than I did because I saw some people saying using filebeats is the newest lightweight way to do it so I wanted to get all the information before doing it the legacy way.

Comment: I appreciate the information, I am aware that I could do this the hard way with fulltext and databases but that means basically recreating a mini search engine for an ecommerce site which will definitely not be as powerful or smart as elasticsearch and that will lead to a lot of money being lost for the company in sales that would have happened if we had a better search engine.

Answer (score 0):

A typical way would be to use Debezium for CDC and Kafka to stream the events to other databases (like Elasticsearch).

Debezium have a nice blog post about doing this with MySQL that you could adapt for MSSQL: https://debezium.io/blog/2018/01/17/streaming-to-elasticsearch/

But if you can possibly avoid it, do not do it this way. It's a complexity explosion.

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate the knowledge. If nothing else this is enough to spark more research. I'm building an e-commerce website and I need visitors to be able to search through the products and categories. So if this works and I haven't seen any other way then I don't think I have much of a choice.